# Email verification. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: laravel, smtp

I'm trying to implement email verification and i'm following a [tutorial](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-58-email-verification-exampleexample.html) but its showing this error:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. #10061]

this is my .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=e9a7e9d32adaf9
MAIL_PASSWORD=58b926579ce74d
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Example
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tsl
```

I already tried this :

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Any help is much appreciated ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

I just change the port and encryption

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=e9a7e9d32adaf9
MAIL_PASSWORD=58b926579ce74d
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Example
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```